# Pandas: Check if Series of strings is in Series with list of strings

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I'm looking for a way to decide if a `pandas` Series of strings is contained in the values of a list of strings of another Series.

Preferably a one-liner - I'm aware that I can solve this by looping over the rows and building up a new series.

**Example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'value': 'foo', 'accepted_values': ['foo', 'bar']},
    {'value': 'bar', 'accepted_values': ['foo']},   
])
```

Desired output would be

```py
pd.Series([True, False])
```

because `'foo'` is in `['foo', 'bar']`, but `'bar'` is not in `['foo']`

**What I've tried:**

- `df['value'].isin(df['accepted_values'])`, but that gives me `[False, False]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `in`:

```
df.apply(lambda r: r.value in r.accepted_values, axis=1)

0     True
1    False
```

Comment: Thanks.
Bonus question: Is there a similar approach when I have two independent series, e.g. one series `value` another one `accepted_values` (not in the same `df`)?
Of course I can always stick them into the same df and use the suggested approach ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are more efficient ways to carry out this operation.

Creating sample data for performance testing

```
    list_strings = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'strawberry', 'elephant', 'butterfly', 'rainbow', 'computer']
    
    rows_shape = 2_000_000
    df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[random.sample(list_strings, 1)[0] for y in range(rows_shape)],
                       'accepted_values':[random.sample(list_strings, 3) for y in range(rows_shape)]})
```

| index | value | accepted_values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | computer | `[orange, computer, pineapple]` |
| 1 | butterfly | `[banana, apple, orange]` |
| 2 | pineapple | `[elephant, computer, butterfly]` |
| 3 | pineapple | `[orange, elephant, apple]` |
| 4 | butterfly | `[elephant, butterfly, strawberry]` |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 999995 | rainbow | `[computer, strawberry, rainbow]` |
| 999996 | pineapple | `[banana, apple, computer]` |
| 999997 | orange | `[butterfly, banana, rainbow]` |
| 999998 | rainbow | `[strawberry, banana, butterfly]` |
| 999999 | strawberry | `[strawberry, rainbow, elephant]` |

```
    # 4.6 seconds - Using .apply
    df.assign(check=lambda x:x.apply(lambda row:row['value'] in row['accepted_values'],axis=1))
    
    # 0.431 seconds - Using Pandas Vectorized Operations
    df.assign(check=lambda z:
              z.pipe(lambda x:(
                  x[['value','accepted_values']]
                  .explode('accepted_values')
                  .pipe(lambda x:x['value'].eq(x['accepted_values']))
                  .groupby(level=0)
                  .any()))
             )

    # 0.124 seconds - Using Numpy Vectorized Operations
    df.assign(check=lambda x:x.pipe(lambda data: np.vectorize(
        lambda value, accepted_values: value in accepted_values)
                                    (data['value'].values,  
                                     data['accepted_values'].values)))
```

| index | value | accepted_values | check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | computer | `[orange, computer, pineapple]` | True |
| 1 | butterfly | `[banana, apple, orange]` | False |
| 2 | pineapple | `[elephant, computer, butterfly]` | False |
| 3 | pineapple | `[orange, elephant, apple]` | False |
| 4 | butterfly | `[elephant, butterfly, strawberry]` | True |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 999995 | rainbow | `[computer, strawberry, rainbow]` | True |
| 999996 | pineapple | `[banana, apple, computer]` | False |
| 999997 | orange | `[butterfly, banana, rainbow]` | False |
| 999998 | rainbow | `[strawberry, banana, butterfly]` | False |
| 999999 | strawberry | `[strawberry, rainbow, elephant]` | True |

vectorized pandas is **x11 faster** than using apply.
vectorized numpy is **x38 faster**!

The strategy employed focused on utilizing Vectorized Operations for enhanced efficiency. Conversely, the apply method internally iterates through loops, resulting in slower processing and should be avoided whenever feasible.